# SQLite3 shell not updating values

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm in the sqlite3 shell, and I'm trying to see why my update isn't recording. In python I'm calling it like:

```
db.execute("UPDATE total SET amount = amount + ?", [DONATION])
db.commit()
```

And in the shell like:

```
sqlite> .schema total
CREATE TABLE total(
    amount REAL);
sqlite> select * from total;
sqlite> update total set amount = 0.002;
sqlite> select * from total;
sqlite>
```

Both cases the value is never getting updated. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert first:

```
sqlite> insert into total values (0.0);
```

Now you can do:

```
sqlite> update total set amount = 0.002;
```

Comment: The absence of a WHERE clause has nothing to do with this problem. (And `> -1` is silly, because then you can never go out of debt.)

Comment: @CL. critique adopted.